# post / redirect / get -- even on errors?

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications

When a user fills out a web form successfully, I always update the database, then redirect to a confirmation page which selects from the database.  However if there is an error in the form, I simply redisplay the form with the user's input and error messages.  It would be somewhat awkward to save all the user's input and the error messages in "session" just to conform to post / redirect / get.  Am I right in this?

Answer (score 2):

Use PRG only if you want to be able to open the page straight without using a form so that it can be bookmarked, linked elsewhere, navigated back in browser history, etc.

You don't want to have that on validation errors (and IMO also not on a confirmation page, it should however take place when confirmation has succeed).

Comment: I don't think you understood what I met by "confirmation page"... what I mean is **not** the user confirming something... it's the **app** confirming that the form submission succeeded.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expect that you meant something else than the global meaning of this term. In the future please use "result page".